# default django model filed with value from the immediatelly previous entry

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, field

I have an app thats supposed to track time, and one of the entries (call it begin_sec) should have (or default to)the value of a previous entry's variable (call it end_sec) (unless its the very first entry a special case that will only happen once ).

here is my model

```
TimeLog(model.Model);
    begin_sec= models.DateTimeField( auto_now=False,
                                   auto_now_add=False,
                                   default=?
                                   help_text="YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS")
    end_sec = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=False,
                                   auto_now_add=False,
                                   default=?
                                   help_text="YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS")

    ... other parts of the model.
```

So when i add a new entry of this type, the first time i open the app as a user i can have the begin time default to now(), and i can choose the end_sec, but on the second time and beyond i want the begin_sec to be/default to the  end_sec of the last entry. 
How would i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify the `default` value in this case. The best place to do that is in the model form `save` method:

```
class TimeLogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['begin_sec']
        model = TimeLog

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(TimeLogForm).__init__(self, *args, **kw)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        instance = super(TimeLogForm, self).save(commit=False)
        last_entry = TimeLog.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
        if last_entry:
            instance.begin_sec = last_entry.begin_sec
        else:
            # this is the very first record do something
            pass
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Also you don't need to set `auto_now=False` and `auto_now_add=False` for both fields, by default they are `False`.

Comment: should'nt  def __ intit __    be rather  def __ init __   ?

Comment: @mike yes it should be `__init__`. Sorry a typo. I have fixed it now.

Comment: i dunno whether this should be a separate question, suppose i wanted to filter the objects by request.user how would i do that?  TimeLog.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0] << in this line

Comment: @mike use this `TimeLog.objects.filter(user__id=user.id).order_by('-id')[0] ` It would be better if you post actual model so that I can give you accurate query to filter by user if you don't understand.

Comment: i was able to figure it out, so no worry.